# Google Drive API Permissions error when attempting to create permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am attempting to create a google spreadsheet using the google sheets api and then update the permissions of the sheet file to have a new owner using the Google Drive API.

I am getting the following error even though I am passing the value as per the doc:

> An error occurred while creating permission: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1xVPxNHQmbO2RSbzbTg7K3qLa8fURP3S_xkIStMVIpK8/permissions?alt=json returned "Permission value field required". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'message': 'Permission value field required', 'locationType': 'other', 'location': 'permission.value'}]">

I am using the below code snippet taken from google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert#python):

```
def driveService(fileID, email):
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2')
    insert_permission(drive_service, fileID, email, "user", "owner")


def insert_permission(service, file_id, email, perm_type, role):
  """Insert a new permission.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to insert permission for.
    value: User or group e-mail address, domain name or None for 'default'
           type.
    perm_type: The value 'user', 'group', 'domain' or 'default'.
    role: The value 'owner', 'writer' or 'reader'.
  Returns:
    The inserted permission if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  
  new_permission = {
      'type': perm_type,
      'role': role,
      'value': email
  }
  
  try:
    return service.permissions().insert(
        fileId=file_id, body=new_permission).execute()
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred while creating permission: %s' % error)
  return None
```

Comment: You should be using drive v3 not drive v2 for starters.

Comment: When I update to 
```drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')```
I get the error " return service.permissions().insert(
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'insert'"

Comment: Thats becouse drive 3 is different you use [permissions create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: Gotcha. what is the proper format for the permissions? Getting the below error but I passed it in the value field as per the reference document. ```"<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1xVPxNHQmbO2RSbzbTg7K3qLa8fURP3S_xkIStMVIpK8/permissions?alt=json returned "The emailAddress field is required for permissions of type 'user' or 'group'.". Details: "[{'message': "The emailAddress field is required for permissions of type 'user' or 'group'.", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'location': 'permission.emailAddress', 'locationType': 'other'}]">"```

Answer (score 0):

Try this let me know if it doesnt work i will make a full sample tomrrow.

```
permission1 = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer',
    'emailAddress': '###',  # Email of Google account.
}
service.permissions().create(fileId=fileId, body=permission1).execute()
permission2 = {
    'type': 'anyone',
    'role': 'writer',
}
service.permissions().create(fileId=fileId, body=permission2).execute()
```